# Showing User's Location in Android

Tags: android, location, location-provider

I have a problem in getting the user's location (my location). My code is

```
double lat;
double lng;
LocationManager locationManager;
String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE; 
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);
String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)){
 locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(provider, true);
}
boolean enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider);
if(enabled){
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"provider enabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"provider disabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
if(location!=null){
  lat = location.getLatitude();
  lng = location.getLongitude();
  AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
  ab.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b><font color=#ff0000>Location" +"</font></b><br>"
            +location.toString()+"<br>Latitude: "+lat
                +"<br>Longitude "+lng));
  ab.setPositiveButton("ok",null );
  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"You are at     "+location.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Location not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

My problem is I am getting the location as `null` while the application message provider is enabled. I have not found any problem in this code. I have also tested it on a device, it shows the provider is enabled and the location isn't found.

I have not implemented the location listener in the class.
Is it necessary to implement location listener in my class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only getting the last known location from the phone. If this is null, which it is if no last known location is available, you are not trying to receive locations in any other way.

You should implement a LocationListener an register it to receive location updates according to this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html This will cause the phone to try to get the users location and hand it over to your application in the form of a Location object.

Comment: Thank you Pich for your tip I have add location listner in my code and it work fine and showing location but I it not work on emulator. AVD get shutdown when I user Location Listner but work fine on device

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted, else the question will remain unanswered.